# How to create second sheet in Excel file using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I want to create two different Excel sheets in a single Excel file. I am using an HTML table to create an Excel sheet and I want to create a second Excel sheet by using the HTML table. Below is my code to create and download the Excel file:

```
 StringBuilder _String = new StringBuilder();

 _String.Append(" <table border=\"1\" style=\"text-align: center; border-collapse: collapse;font-family: Arial, Helvetica,
     sans-serif; font-size: 13px;\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"0\">");


_String.Append("<tr>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; height:70px; vertical-align:middle; \" rowspan=\"4\">");
_String.Append("&nbsp;");
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;height:70px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; \"
     rowspan=\"4\">");
_String.Append(Convert.ToString(_Count));
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;height:70px; vertical-align:middle;  text-align:center; \"
     rowspan=\"4\">");
_String.Append(Location);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;height:70px; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; \"
     rowspan=\"4\">");
_String.Append(ATMCode);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;  height:70px; vertical-align:middle;background-color: #c0c0c0;\"
     rowspan=\"4\">");
_String.Append("&nbsp;");
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; text-align:center;  height:70px;
     vertical-align:middle;background-color: #c0c0c0;\" rowspan=\"4\">");
_String.Append(Time);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; text-align:center; \">");
_String.Append("1000");
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;  background-color: #c0c0c0;\">");
_String.Append(OpeningBal_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; \">");
_String.Append(OpeningBalAm_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;  background-color: #c0c0c0;\">");
_String.Append(Dispense_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; \">");
_String.Append(DispenseAm_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;  background-color: #c0c0c0;\">");
_String.Append(Purge_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; \">");
_String.Append(PurgeAm_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;  background-color: #c0c0c0;\">");
_String.Append(Overages_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; \">");
_String.Append(OveragesAm_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;  background-color: #c0c0c0;\">");
_String.Append(shortages_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; \">");
_String.Append(shortagesAm_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; \">");
_String.Append(ClosingBR_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; \">");
_String.Append(ClosingBRAm_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;  background-color: #c0c0c0;\">");
_String.Append(Rep_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; \">");
_String.Append(RepAm_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; \">");
_String.Append(CB_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; \">");
_String.Append(CBAm_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;  background-color: #c0c0c0;\">");
_String.Append(TxnNumber);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;  background-color: #c0c0c0;\">");
_String.Append("&nbsp;");
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;  background-color: #c0c0c0;\">");
_String.Append(Deposit);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;  background-color: #c0c0c0;\">");
_String.Append(Deposit);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;  background-color: #c0c0c0;\">");
_String.Append(RetainedCrd);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; background-color: #c0c0c0;\">");
_String.Append("&nbsp;");
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;  background-color: #c0c0c0;\">");
_String.Append(SCB_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; \">");
_String.Append(SCBAm_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;  background-color: #c0c0c0;\" rowspan=\"4\">");
_String.Append("&nbsp;");
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px;  background-color: #c0c0c0;\">");
_String.Append(OpeningBal_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; \">");
_String.Append(OpeningBalAm_1000);
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("<td style=\"padding: 4px; margin: 3px; 
    height:70px; background-color:#CCFFCC;Color:#2E6C31;
    vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;\" rowspan=\"4\">");
_String.Append("<b>" + Status + "</b>");
_String.Append("</td>");
_String.Append("</tr>");
_String.Append("</table>");
```

Download code:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;
filename=ExcelFile.xls"); Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Response.Write(_String.ToString()); Response.End();
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use some library to create the xls file in server-side. If the content is not too complicated, I recommend ClosedXML - just google it.

Comment: I think U didn't get my question . I am Downloading single excel file from code above in c# what i want is to download one more excel file within same excel sheet . i am using HTML table to create excel file u can get reference from code above

Comment: Your first sentence: "I wanna create two different excel sheet in a single excel file". I just gave an answer of how you can achive it. With ClosedXML you can make more sheets

Comment: Could you please attach a sample code that would help me in downloading two excel file in single workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got am alternative for this can be done using EPPlus library .Its the simplest way of doing it

Answer (score 2):

I attach some code. But I am confused because you write "two excel file in single workbook". It make no sense. So I give you a code to create one excel file with two sheets:

So, download ClosedXML it is a Open Source Project. http://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Add the reference in visual studio to you project's references:

[image]

Create an excel file serverside:

Create the workbook

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
```

Add a worksheet:

```
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheetName");
```

Attach data to sheet:

example:

```
worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "someData";
```

Add another worksheet:

```
var worksheet2 = workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheetName2");
```

Save the file

```
//path can be this
//string path = Server.MapPath(~/DirectoryInYourProject/FileName.xlsx);

workbook.SaveAs(path);
```

If you use ASP.NET MVC: code to download in your controller

```
return File(
    path,
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    "FileName.xlsx");
```

If you use Web Froms: code to download in code behind:

```
   System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.ClearContent();
    response.Clear();
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +  "FileName.xlsx;");
    response.TransmitFile(path);
    response.Flush();
    response.End();
```

I think it's the best way. To make "download as excel" function. Of course it can be made several ways, I just give you that I know about. For using ClosedXML there is a lot of example in it's site.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time .Hi @jannagy02 hi have attached the image above for your reference (which is highlighted in yellow portion) . In this excel file image CBR contains different design ,VCB contains different designs respectively.Please help me in achieving this.

Comment: So just create an XLWorkbook add the WorkSheets to it and fill with data using the API of ClosedXML. Set the colors etc. It can be done by the API. There is a lot of example code to learn from: http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Showcase&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: I think this question gets asked repeatedly because to often the response is yet another third party library and many people would like an answer that doesn't require a library be added/updated for every deployment.